# Background color when rotating image view

Tags: android-studio

I want to rotate an image view by different degrees but i don't understand why there is a light blue background when it is rotated. I am also unable to find where this color came from as it is not in my project folder.

[Before the image view is rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Yom.jpg)

[After the image view is rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quc5X.jpg)